# dynamic object creation in c++?

Tags: c++

If my class name is TEST i want to create an object of TEST class having name given by the user during run time??
i tried this-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class TEST
{
   void end()
   {
      cout<<"Hi";
   }
};
   int main()
{
  string name;
  cout<<"Give a object name";
  cin>>name;//taking name from user
  TEST name;//here i am getting error while creating object of TEST class 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error messages exist for a reason.

Comment: give me the reason and the solution to solve this problem

Comment: @AnkitAbhinav You cannot use the variable symbol `name` twice in the same scope.

Comment: if copy the string in the other string variable and the try to create the object,then also it gives error.. "string s1 the strcpy(s1,name), then TEST s1"

Comment: @mmking u can also face the same problem if u go and work with real time problems

Comment: @AnkitAbhinav "give me the reason and the solution to solve this problem" I'll give you a downvote instead

Comment: You can't specify a variable name at run-time; variable names exist only at compile time. Perhaps you could describe why you want to give it a run-time name, so we could suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: You cannot achieve this using c++. Variable "names" only exist up to the point of compilation, and what you want to do is assign a variable a name at runtime which is clearly after the compilation.

Comment: I have a feeling you want some mapping from entered strings to objects like a `std::unordered_map`, such that you can enter the same string later and access that object because the string is the key.

Comment: @Mike Seymour i got this problem in a coding event.

Comment: @AnkitAbhinav So you're trying to learn c++ on the fly at a _coding event_? o_O

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do here, except perhaps learning basic c++ constructs.  Here is some code to get you going.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class TEST
{
public:
    //Constructor - sets member string to input
    TEST( string input ) : _name( input )
    {
    }

    //Destructor called when object goes out of scope
    ~TEST()
    {
       cout << "Hi from destructor" << endl;
    }

    //Variable stored by the class
    string _name;
};

int main()
{
    string inputString;

    cout << "Give a object name";
    cin >> inputString;

    // Give name to your class instance through the constructor
    TEST foo( inputString );

    // Store a copy of the object "foo" in a map that can be referenced by name
    map< string, TEST > userNamedObjects;
    userNamedObjects.insert( { inputString, foo } );

    // Access the object's data based on user input name
    cout << "From map: " << userNamedObjects.at( inputString )._name << endl;

    // Sanity check
    cout << foo._name << endl;

    // Or set it directly
    foo._name = "Patrick Swayze";

    cout << foo._name << endl;

    // The stored object doesn't change, because it's a copy
    cout << "From map: " << userNamedObjects.at( inputString )._name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your attempt is very helpful it helps a lot but actually the problem what i am handling is object name should be given by user.. rely thanks a lot  for the answer

Comment: @AnkitAbhinav What about using `std::map<std::string, TEST>`?

Comment: Ok, I added some code showing Neil's idea. This uses a std::map to store the object with a string key being the user's input name. I updated everything else so that it compiles. :P

Comment: @AnkitAbhinav _"but actually the problem what i am handling is object name should be given by user.. "_ How isn't that done in the answer??